# getting object not found! Error on xampp while the file exist

Tags: object, xampp

following is my url structure,and path to file is in the image[image: Have a look at this image for path]
"http://localhost/applechat/register/index.php"
when i type this url in the browser my url change to this
"http://localhost/applechat/register/localhost"
and i get the Object Not Found Error!
what could be the possible reason?

Comment: verify you index.php, probably it's redirecting to another URL.

Comment: but why redirecting?

Comment: just to discard,  try to crate another folder insde htdocs example : test/index.html, and try to access.

Comment: resolved, Thanks.